# How to see the resolved proxy_pass URL in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-config

I have a setup like this for reflecting requests:

```
location ~ ^/prefix/string/(.*)$
{
   proxy_pass https://abc.example.com/$1;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/unique.log logformat
}
```

1. Visit my site at `/prefix/string/more_stuff`
2. Logs show 404 with `$upstream_addr` only containing the IP of `abc.example.com`,
   *not* the full URL
3. Log lines show up in `unique.log`, so I know I'm hitting this location block.
4. I want to eliminate the possibility that the URL construction with `$1` is wrong.
5. I would like to be able to log the *resolved* complete `proxy_pass` URL so I can
   fix it or move on to other types of debugging.

Note: I realize that I can read docs to figure out nginx's behavior in this case.  But just logging the resolved URL would be way faster if possible.

Question: How to log the resolved URL that NGINX actually visits for a `proxy_pass` like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [named capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) to capture your URI suffix as some unique variable instead of `$1`:

```
location ~ ^/prefix/string/(?<suffix>.*)$ {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/unique.log unique;
    proxy_pass https://abc.example.com/$suffix;
}
```

Define a new `unique` log format at the **http** context level (for example, adding this `$suffix` value to the default `combined` log format):

```
# should be defined outside the server block!
log_format  unique  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
                    ' Proxy path: "$suffix"';
server {
    ...
}
```